# How to remove brackets and quote when displaying array results - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel & working on my first project. A small issue I am having is when I build a collection (array) and insert results into Laravel Form Select, and export to Excel, my results are wrapped in ["array"] brackets and quotes.

Code to build the collection:

```
                   $p3 = DB::table('players')
                       ->where ('id', $player3)
                       ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
                       ->pluck('full_name', 'id');

                   $played['p'] .= $p3;

                   $p4 = DB::table('players')
                       ->where ('id', $player4)
                       ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
                       ->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Note, there are 16 above (grabbing names from associated table)... I then build the collection:

```
$played = collect([$p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8, $p9, $p10, $p11, $p12, $p13, $p14, $p15, $p16]);
```

and pass to view:

```
return view('grades.matchcard.edit', compact('data','data1', 'played', 'mid'));
```

[image]

As per image, the results are wrapped in brackets/quotes... Same when I export to Excel... I tried join & implode (get errors). Tried using

str_replace (kind of worked - but not great...

Any sugggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your DB queries generates a collection of one element, and then you collect those collections into your final `$played` variable.  So iterating over it, each item is actually another collection.  You want to [`flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-flatten) the collections, like so:

```
$played = collect([$p1, $p2, ...])->flatten();
```

BTW, I don't see the rest of your code but the chunk you've shown is quite inefficient, and might be better written:

```
$played = DB::table('players')
->whereIn('id', [$player3, $player4, $player5 .... all your ids ...])
->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Here you are doing just one DB query, instead of many, and the query returns your collection, no need for further collecting and flattening.  [More info in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses).

**UPDATE** to clarify based on comments:

The `pluck()` method above keys the resulting collection by the second parameter.  So `$played` should be a collection of correctly matched `id => full_name` elements.  To display the player with id 3's full name, you should be able to use `$played[3]`.

BTW: do you have a `Player` model?  If not, to do things the neat Laravel way you probably should, and it would make things a lot simpler.  For eg:

**In your model**

Define an accessor, to make getting full name easier.

```
public function getFullNameAttribute($value) {
    return $value->fname . ' ' . $value->lname;
}
```

[More info about accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the docs.

**In your controller**

```
$players = App\Player::find([$player3, $player4, $player5 .... all your ids ...]);
return view('whatever.your.view.is', ['players' => $players]);
```

[More info about retrieving models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models) in the docs.

**In your view**

```
<select>
@foreach ($players as $player)        
    <option value='{{ $player->id }}'>{{ $player->full_name }}</option>
</select>
@endforeach
```

If you want players to be listed in a particular order, you should either define that order in your model/database (eg a players.ranking field?), or, if the order is based on something derivable you could order it on the fly.  Eg if you need them alphabetical you can add `->orderBy('lname')` to the `$players` query in your controller.

Comment: Oops I just noticed I had the `[$p1, ... ]` array in the wrong place, fixed.  Did that solve the problem for you?

Comment: Thanks Don't Panic... Almost there... 

$played=collect([$player])->flatten(); (after your revised single query)

Only issue is that in the players are in a specific order (hence, $p1, $p2  to $p16). When I query the array based on order (e.g {{ $played[1] }} in blade which should return $p2 full_name - its not - it is displaying the names in a different order). Also, the "ID" is not part of the array - just the full_name - I need the ID to return later.

Hope that makes sense? Sorry my limited experience here - its probably something very simple... thanks again!

Comment: @Jimmy Sounds like there is more to your question than you initially mentioned! The `pluck` code I posted will give you the ID, correctly mapped to the right name ... if you're not seeing it there's something else getting in the way.  I've updated my answer, and added a description of how to do this the correct Laravel way.

Comment: Thank you VERY much @Don't Panic... Huge help.... Its all fundamentally working nicely. My ONLY issue currently is the order of the array results (which is technically not part of my initial question). I am researching, and some people mention a orderByRaw(FIELD(.... type clause which I play around with - but otherwise, you have solved my main issue - thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks again... Sorry first Q on Stack - didnt know I had to do that :) - all done

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$p4 = DB::table('players')
->where ('id', $player4)
->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
->get();
```

And in blade

```
{{$p4->id}}
{{$p4->full_name}}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry i didnt see the hole question

you can do something like this

```
$p4 = DB::table('players')
   ->where ('id', $player4)
   ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
   ->get();

$played = new Collection();
$played.push($p4);
```

And in blade this should work

```
@foreach($played as $object)
    {{$object->id}}
    {{$object->full_name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I agree with @Leonardo. You are inserting your $p4 variable (an array) into another array, and assigning that to $played. So you are having trouble when you access the value because it is two arrays deep.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo - its working! My only issues (1. I would love to get Don't panics single query working instead of 16) and I cant get the FULL array to display in Form::Select with the default being the current value.

I am trying to achieve:
{!! Form::select('capt', $played, $played[0], ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

Where I list ALL names in the drop down and the default is current $played[0] in this case, next select would be $played[1] and so forth.

I am not using foreach - just trying to pass the FULL list and the current for each of the 16 selects. Does that make sense?